# regular expressions in python script

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python. I need to find the words in a list that contains these vowels using regular expressions. The following does not work. Can anyone see what needs to be corrected? Thank you.

```
import re
file = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
print re.findall('[aie]', file)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\MyScripts\script2.py", line 3, in ` <module>
        print re.findall('[aie]', file)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 181, in findall
        return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Here is what is in the wordlist, which I can retrieve by using this:

```
file = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
print file.read()`
```

Prints out:

```
ae
The 
Intelligent 
Assistance 
Revolution 
may 
not 
be 
televised 
but 
it 
will 
definitely 
be
```

Comment: Not that I knew Python, but it seems that findall expects a string, not a file...

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. I'll have to practice. This is my first question and could not get it to print correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.findall()` doesn't accept a file object, as the error says you need to pass a string or buffer so you can use `file.read()` to pass the file as a string object to `findall()` function :

```
print re.findall('[aie]', file.read())
```

Or as a more pythonic way if you are dealing with huge files for refusing of reading the file at once, you can loop over your file and based on your need use `re.search` or `re.fildall` for each line.

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      #do stuff with line
```

Comment: thanks so much for the detail. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the problem. Very new to python. thanks! I'm taking notes.

Comment: @angelica Welcome, so if you have found this answer helpful you can tell this to community by [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer ;)

Comment: I immediately tried to accept the answer but I got a pop-up saying that I could not accept an answer til I got a reputation of 15 points! Since I just started, I could not do that. After I get 15 points, I will come back to this and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
import re
file = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
print re.findall('[aie]', file.read())
```

The error is due to the fact you are trying implement on a file object not it is content

Comment: thanks so much. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the problem. Very new to python. thanks!

Comment: @angelica happy to help :)\